# Adding and Uploading documents to a central document Library from subsites

Tags: document-library

Is there some way to link an existing centralised document library to a new subsite?

In order to prevent users from saving documents in scattered places all over our website, we have our site definition remove the (new) Document Library that is created whenever a new site is created. Is there any way to programmatically add a short cut to the centralised document library, so when a user adds or uploads a file they are seamlessly redirected to or can easily select the central document library?

Answer (score 1):

This may be slightly simplistic but sometimes those are the things that get overlooked.

If you have deleted the OOTB document library on your site definintion then there is no reference to this on the site.

Surely you just need to edit the navigation and add a link to your central document library, you just need to ensure that your sub-site users have approriate permissions on the document library in question.

Or have I missed an obvious requirement here?

**Hint:**  Look to the SPWeb.Navigation class for how to do this programatically:
http://vspug.com/tbaginski/2007/12/26/how-to-programmatically-customize-site-navigation-in-wss-3-0-and-moss-2007/

Comment: We were wanting to redirect the uploaded document behind the scenes, without the user having to choose the library in the Document Centre. It looks like we'll end up using the Content Organiser feature to do this for us.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the same behavour as exhibited by "Send To" option in the ECB menu of a document library, which sends a copy os the document to configured doc library.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote my first blog post about this very topic: http://sharepointantihero.wordpress.com/